# V8 / JS runtime: how are JavaScript window functions available without prefix "window"

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, v8, prototypal-inheritance

I don't know much about the JS console but I'm moving into command line programming and it would be good to know my native environment before I start using shell/node in a foreign one

My guess is that all command line statements are invoked `with (window) eval(/* whatever user typed before hitting enter/*)` but this seems like horrible practice. The context is definitely bound as "Window" if I `console.log(this)` but I'm not sure why / how

It's almost like the user `cd`'d into the window object to set it as the context

Comment: there's no `window` object in Node.  There's a global context, but things work somewhat differently in Node than in the browser.

Comment: What are you asking? about command line? about `window`? and if so, do you expect there to be an equivalent of `window.scrollX` (for example)? (there isn't...)

Comment: This is just how the global scope works. The top-level scope is an object environment bound to the global object (`window` in browsers, `global` in node)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All JavaScript has a global scope. In the browser, the global scope is called "window" and it is a reference to the window object. In node, it is called "global" and refers to the global JS namespace in node.

The "window" global in a browser has a bunch of properties on it. Things like "console" or "location". When you want to talk to those pieces of code, you can optionally prefix the call with "window.". Example: to log something to the console you can type:

```
window.console.log("HELLO");
```

or you can leave the "window." off of the call, like such:

```
console.log("HELLO");
```

The global "window" object in the browser is the only optional object on the page. Any time you see a reference to a variable that wasn't declared using "var" (or "let" and "const" in ES6), that means that the variable is just a property on the global object.

Comment: right, i can see a global variable being available if it was `var console = function  () {}` but i believe it's actually `window.console = function () {...}` or `window = (function () {this.console = function () {...}})()` rather than `window` being some functional scope that we're live adding lines to right??

Comment: Edited my response to include the answer for you.